# Converting unicode in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text field where customers can provide IP address ranges. Apparently, one of them copied and pasted a range from a document into the text field. While it looked perfectly fine, there was actually a `\u2010` character that got pasted into the spreadsheet into the text field.

As a result, the IP address range they thought they were providing was `192.168.1.1-255`; however, a `.dump` on that string in the database revealed `192.168.1\u2010255`.

In Rails, how can I ensure this doesn't happen again with this character or any other character? Not sure if I can just convert this to the hypen it was supposed to be, et.c

Answer (score 0):

how about set a regex pattern validation for text field

```rb
<%= form.text_field :ip_range, pattern: '^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}$' %>
```

Comment: Also add a validation to the model. Form field validation is nice to the user, but doesn't ensure anything (easy to bypass). Model validation ensures data integrity.

Comment: We did have validations at one point, but then users would get the "X.X.X.X is not a valid IP address" error message, not knowing there are invisible characters. I guess an alternative would be to strip out invalid characters when they paste (and we must allow copy/paste of course for large IP ranges)

Comment: @max you mean this: https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/ ?

Comment: Yes. This is a classical case where you want a parser instead of a regex.